# Logo Design using pure CSS

Tags: html, css

So I have seen some really cool things made using CSS and seen some peoples website logo's completed in pure CSS, no images.

I really want to understand how its done, I have drawn out a logo I was going to attempt to redesign using CSS but realized how hard it really is! So to help me understand it a little bit more could someone correct my code so I can understand how its done!

Any help is appreciated :) Thanks.

(p.s awful coding but you can see where I was coming from?)

[image: This is a quick sketch of what I wanted to achieve]

This is a quick sketch of what I wanted to achieve

```css
#logotop{
     height:45px;
     width:90px;
     border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     background:green;
}
#logobottom{
 overflow: hidden;
     height:45px;
     width:45px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 150px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 150px;
 
     background:green;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
    transform: rotate(315deg);

  margin-left: auto ;
   margin-right: auto ;
}
#logocenter{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
     height:55px;
     width:55px;
     border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px ;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px ;
     background:white;
  margin-top: -72px;
  margin-left: auto ;
   margin-right: auto ;
}
#logocenter2{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
     height:25px;
     width:25px;
     border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px ;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px ;
     background:green;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: auto ;
   margin-right: auto ;
 
}
#content{
 height: 90px;
 width: 90px;
 background-color: white;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<div id="logotop">
</div>
<div id="logobottom">
</div>
<div id="logocenter">
</div>
<div id="logocenter2">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best I could do, being at work (in a hospital): [demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m6fag694/](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m6fag694/).

Comment: This is what i wanted to achieve, it looks pretty good to be fair what you have done! you have given me something to start on and ill try edit this and see if i can edit and understand what im doing! My end result i want to rotate the image and do some cool things :) thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

online there is a lot of img to css convertor like [THIS](http://www.imgtocss.com), but you should make a good quality image and try to convert it.

The convetor that I've just suggested to you use a pixel-for-pixel whit a table like that:

```
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height=50 width=50 style="font-size:0px;height:50;width:50">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height=50 width=50 style="font-size:0px;height:50px;width:50px">
        <tr height=0>
          <td width=1 />
          <td width=1 />
          <td width=1 />
          <td width=1 />
          <td width=1 />
          <td width=1 />
          <td width=1 />
          <td width=1 />
          <td width=1 />
          <td width=1 />
          <td width=1 />
          <td width=1 />
        </table
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/madj1453/)

Comment: This is awesome! but looks so sloppy! i will consider a image converter with other simple images :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to explain because there's no "exact rules" to explain.
You can use a tool such like paolobasso's one, but it's a pixel-based tool that just recreate by a matrix (table -> cell) an image.

**What are you talking about instead it's a decomposition of a figure in N rectagles.**

**Each rectangle**

- it's positioned with margins (example: margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto means "centered") and flow (position attribute).
- It's colored by  `background` property.
- It's dimensioned by `width` and `height`.
- It's shaped (curved) by  `border-radius` and similiar to decline to each browser (es: moz-border-radius)
- it's shaped and dimensioned by rotation in degree (`transform: rotate(315deg)`)

So, by hand, it's difficoult to do such things, but if you want to understand you have to study something like OpenGL and not pure css, principles are the same used for 2D graphics, anyway there's nothing much more to say about, rest it's all about css flux and flow to let your "rectangles" stay togheter and stay at correct distance. Often you'll need some overlapping and, if you have a lot of colors (imagine a button over a shirt) to manage also css `z-index` property.

Comment: So what exactly is OpenGL and how can it be used for webdesign?
Ive seen OpenGL in the settings of Counter Strike 1.6 if i recall?

Comment: OpenGL it's the basic about computer graphic. If you look for some classroom-slides or resumes you'll can understand better about basics to create 2D shapes and model to make anything. Principles are the same used in CSS, the 3 basics actions are the same, basically what really "changes" in porting is a container box (in place of an array or object) to translate all the containing shapes. In CSS already exists 2D graphics spec: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp . In CSS you have a small difference also in shaping round circles since you have border-radius.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ill research into it, rather interesting to be fare :)